# Why the selected dropdown value is not getting shown?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, frontend, dropdown

I am building a function on my WordPress plugin where it displays a dropdown of all the available pages. When I click on Save Changes, the value gets saved perfectly in the DB. It updates the value perfectly too. But, the selected value is not being shown in the dropdown. When Save Changes is clicked the value gets saved, but the dropdown again resets to "Choose one". It doesn't get to display the selected option. Am I doing something wrong here? Any guidance is appreciated.

```
<form method=post>
<div class="header-right">
  <?php
  $posts = get_pages(
    array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    )
  );
  
  ?>
  <select name="page_for_logged_in" id="page_for_logged_in">
    <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
    <?php
    foreach ( $posts as $page ) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $page->post_name ); ?>" <?php selected(get_option('page_for_logged_in'), 'page')?>><?php echo esc_html( $page->post_title ); ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
  </select>

  <?php
  if(empty($_POST['page_for_logged_in'])) {
      
    } else {
      $myvalue=$_POST['page_for_logged_in'];
      update_option('page_for_logged_in', $myvalue, $autoload = 'no');
    }
    ?>

<?php submit_button(); ?>

</p>
</br>
</br>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the content of `$posts` or the casted `$array_pages`? Are you sure that there is more then one element inside?

Comment: Hi @KargWare, just noticed that. It was unnecessary. Updated the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out the working solution to my issue. Pasted below; Might be helpful for someone.

```
<form method=post>
    <div class="header-right">
      <?php
      $posts = get_pages(
        array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        )
      );
      
      ?>
      <?php
      if(empty($_POST['page_for_logged_in'])) {
          
        } else {
          $myvalue=$_POST['page_for_logged_in'];
          update_option('page_for_logged_in', $myvalue, $autoload = 'yes');
        }
        ?>
      <select name="page_for_logged_in" id="page_for_logged_in">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose one</option>
        <?php
        foreach ( $posts as $page ) {
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $page->post_title ); ?>" <?php echo ( get_option('page_for_logged_in') == $page->post_title ? 'selected' : '' ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $page->post_title ); ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
      </select>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>

    </p>
    </br>
    </br>
    </form>
```